# c++ if the current time = given time

Tags: c++

i need help i have a simple program but it wont work
here is my code
i want to check if the current system time equals to the given time and do something

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) 


const std::string currentDateTime() {
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);
    
    
    return buf;

}

int main() {
    while (true)
    {
        currentDateTime();
        char * currtimetochar = strcpy(new char[currentDateTime().length() + 1], currentDateTime().c_str());
        //std::cout << idokes << std::endl;
        if (currtimetochar == "2020-08-31.19:29:59")//given time date for example {
        std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
         // do something more 
        }
    }

    getchar();  
}
```

Comment: There's an extra closing bracket after "success". You should delete it.

Comment: You are leaking a whole `char[]` every iteration of your tight potentially infinite loop. You are comparing `currtimetochar` with `"2020-08-31.19:29:59"` which will always be false, because that compares the address of the array `currtimetochar` with the address of the literal the C string "2020-08-31.19:29:59". Just `if(currentDateTime() == "2020-08-31.19:29:59")` will do what you want. Avoid `new` it isn't needed in modern code. See `std::make_unique` instead.

Comment: oh, it was that simple, thank you very much for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to encode a given time string to a LOCALTIME or SYSTEMTIME and compare that instead of comparing strings whose format would change in different locales.  SYSTEMTIME is better for "absolute time comparisons" (it's in UTC) although using LOCALTIME may be sufficient to meet your needs.